# Close friend with non muslim

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, friendship

I have a non-Muslim (*Hindu*) friend ... he mean me no harm. I ask him once if u have a chance will u accept islam. he said no. so now it has been more complicated for me after reciting Ayat no:28 of the quran from surat Al-e-Imran.

> The believers should not make the disbelievers their allies rather than other believers anyone who does such a thing will isolate himself completely from god except when you need to protect yourselves from them god warns you to beware of him:the final return is to god".

I have some muslim friends too....so can I continue the relation with the non believer friend or not??? I need the answer so badly.....

Answer (score 1):

As-salamu alaikum!

In the Name of Allah, the Most Beneficent, the Most Merciful.
"Allah does not forbid you to be kind and good and to deal justly with those who have not fought you because of your faith and have not turned you out of your homes. Allah loves those who are just.(8)
Allah only forbids you to make friends with those who have fought you because of your faith and who have turned you out of your homes and who supported your expulsion. Indeed, those who make friends with them are really the unjust.(9)"
al-Qur'an al-Kareem surat al-Mumtahanah ayat 8-9 (60:8-9)

So there is nothing wrong with being friends with non-Muslims as it is described in the ayah above. Of course, friends can have a influence on oneself and thus friends should be chosen wisely.

Narrated AbuHurayrah: The Prophet, peace be upon him, said: "A man follows the religion of his friend; so each one should consider whom he makes his friend." (Sunan Abi Dawud 4833)